# Crossrider : Using mouse position in context menu

Tags: crossrider

We would like to use appAPI.openURL but in place of sending the data.selectedText I woould like to send the text of the element under the mouse. But I can't find the way of getting the mouse position. My idea was to add in the appAPI.ready the following

```
$().mousemove(function(event) {
myPositionX = event.pageX ;
myPositionY = event.pageY ;
}
```

And to have two global variable `myPositionX`  and `myPositionY` which I could access in my background code to transmit as parameters of my URL.
But this doesn't seem to work.
Is what I'm doing crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be pleased to note that your are not crazy but simply missed the selector required to attach the handler to the page. Hence, to make you code work, bind the **mousemove** handler to the **document** object per the following tried and tested code:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    myPositionX = event.pageX ;
    myPositionY = event.pageY ;
});
```